# Custom function needs to be activated by clicking on a custom menu

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps, custom-function, google-apps-script-addon

I published a Google Sheet add-on privately.

When I install it, a new Google sheet is systematically opened, the custom function works. However, if I create a new Google Sheet, the custom function does not work in the first place. I need to click `Add-ons ==> TotallyNew ==> Use`, which opens the sidebar, and the custom function works as well.

I just don't understand why the custom function is activated by `Use`.

Does anyone know the reason?

```
function myFun() {
  console.log("inside myFun");
  return "myFunValue"
}

function onInstall(e) {
  console.info("inside onInstall");
  onOpen(e);
}

function onOpen(e) {
  console.info("inside onOpen");
  console.info(e.authMode);

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createAddonMenu()
      .addItem('Use', 'use')
      .addToUi();
}

function use() {
  console.info("inside Use")
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index.html')
      .setTitle('My custom sidebar')
      .setWidth(300);

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .showSidebar(html)
}
```

Comment: This page might help: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus

Comment: This might also help: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/docs

Answer (score 0):

You are close.  Change `createAddonMenu` to `createMenu`

```
function onOpen(e) {
  console.info("inside onOpen");
  console.info(e.authMode);

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu()
      .addItem('Use', 'use')
      .addToUi();
}
```

Comment: When I `Test as add-on`, it gives me an error in the console: `Google Apps Script: Cannot find method createMenu().`, and I cannot find the menu.

Comment: I tried `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('myMenu').addItem('Use2', 'use').addToUi();`, it had the same problem as `createAddonMenu` with regard to custom functions.